# Can't Add Image in mPDF

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am trying to add an image file to my mpdf generated pdf.
My generatepdf.php file is here,

```
<?php
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');

            $date1  = $_POST['date1'];
            $date2  = $_POST['date2'];
            $date3 = $_POST['date3'];
            $letter = $_POST['letter'];


$html .= "
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<!--mpdf

<h3 align=center><b>DEMO CONTENT</b></h3>

<htmlpagefooter name='myfooter'>
<div style='border-top: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 9pt; text-align:         
center; padding-top: 3mm; '>
Page {PAGENO} of {nb}
</div>
</htmlpagefooter>


<sethtmlpagefooter name='myfooter' value='on' />
mpdf-->


<p style='font-size: 13pt;text-align:center;'>Some Text Here with $date1 and $date2 Some Text Here:</p>



<pagebreak /><legend>A Letter Here : </legend><br/>
<p>             To, <br/>
           Someone<br/>
           Some Company<br/>

    <p>Sir,</p><br/>
    $letter

     <p align=right>
     <img src="./images/soi.jpg"/><br/>
     Some text,<br/><br/>




</body>
</html>
";

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');


$mpdf->Output();

exit;

?>
```

The above code gives an error. It cannot understand the  tag.
I tried many methods but none of them worked. Where I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state your version of mPDF.

Comment: Does everything else work?  Is the image path correct?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of what you are generating.  Is the image tag displaying as unrendered? Or nothing at all in the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the double quotes like this `\"` because your content in `$html` is declared using double quotes.

```
<image src="./images/soi.jpg"/><br/>
```

should be

```
<img src=\"./images/soi.jpg\"/><br/>
```

Also, unless you actually mean to concatenate the `$html` value...

```
$html .= "
```

could/should be

```
$html = "
```

Comment: Didn't worked. Pdf is generating but still not showing the image. :-(

Comment: Also your p tag doesn't close.  Try to tidy up the dom ( ensure all tags are closed.)

Comment: @NemoL change your image tag from `<image` to `<img`

Comment: Thanks. :-) It worked. But when I added <img src=\"images/soi.jpg\" width="50%" />, it starts showing **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '50' (T_LNUMBER)**

Comment: @NemoL again you will need to escape your double quotes with  \   `width=\"50%\"`.

Comment: The code is working but the width is not working. It's not becoming 50%. Thanks for replying me back again.

Comment: @NemoL did you validate your tags like I advised in an earlier comment.  Please show me the latest version of your code.

Comment: Are you expecting 50% of the image's original size?  50% of the unclosed `<p>` tag's width? or 50% of the page's width?  It may help to post they original image and the output pdf for comparison.

Comment: @NemoL the p in this line: `<p>             To, <br/>` and this line: `<p align=right>` are never closed.  Please close these tags and retry your pdf generation.

Comment: I've closed the <p> tag on the original code. And I want the image width to be 50% of the page width. I'm very much thankful to you. You're helping me a lot. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @NemoL If the img tag is not nested inside of another element then `width="50%"` or  `style="width:50%;"` will do the trick.  Be sure that there are no p's, div's, etc. restricting the image's ability to expand to 50%.  I hope my answer will soon earn the green tick of approval.

Comment: The reason you can't find your unclosed p tags is because you are not tabbing your code properly.  I'll show you what I mean with a rewrite when I get to my computer this morning.

Comment: @NemoL There is still at least one `<p>` tag issue in your code. You have 1 too many closing `</b>` tags.  Your image width attribute starts with a typo and also doesn't use `50%` as the value.  I have tabbed your code for you to expose the issues that you need to correct: http://codepad.org/Qj1PLwYD  My 3 comment lines are extra long so you won't accidentally overlook them.

Comment: Changed and edited as you said. But didn't worked. [PDF](http://freepdfhosting.com/70ba740df0.pdf)

Comment: @NemoL So is the final problem is that the image is stretching to 100%?  Please show me your latest code.  I have had problems with styling/positioning non-tabular elements, but I would rather not advise you to use a hack like putting your image tag in a table cell.  Let's keep working on it.

Comment: @NemoL `<img src=\"images/soi.jpg\" \width=\"50%\"`  I found your problem.  the  \  is ruining your width declaration.  Change to `<img src=\"images/soi.jpg\" width=\"50%\"` and you should be sweet.